OnPress and Link event doesn't work inside headerRight
I'm using the latest version of React Native with the Expo router:
"expo-router": "~4.0.9",

"expo": "~52.0.11",

However, when I try to implement a Link or onPress event within screenOptions - headerRight, it only works on the emulator and not on a real device.
<Stack
  screenOptions={{
    headerRight: () => (
      <Link href='/cart' asChild>
        <Pressable>
          {({ pressed }) => (
            <FontAwesome
              name='shopping-cart'
              size={25}
              color={Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light'].text}
              style={{ marginRight: 15, opacity: pressed ? 0.5 : 1 }}
            />
          )}
        </Pressable>
      </Link>
    ),
  }}
>

The only fix I've found so far is to use useRouter and navigate on onPressIn.
headerRight: () => {
  const router = useRouter()
  return (
    <Pressable onPressIn={() => router.push('/cart')}>
///other UI

